# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) on project botlibrary: Exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]

Tags: maven, gnupg

When running the verify phase for my maven project, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) on project botlibrary: Exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

My gpg plugin is configured like this:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

What should I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, if anyone comes across this in the future, the issue was that in my settings.xml file, I had specified gpg2 as executable, when it should have been gpg.